# Truncation of keywords in RTF file

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, rtf, keyword

we are embedding data in the `\keywords` field of a RTF file. The `\keywords` tag is updated in the file with sort of "String replacement", not by using any kind of RTF API.

It appears that when we open the RTF file in Word 2007, the keywords property of the file only display the first 520 characters of the `\keywords` tag. If I edit this field directly from Word 2007, with more than 520 characters, it seems ok until I save the file to the disk.

Does it feel to you as the expected behavior? Be able to type keywords of any length in Word but loosing them after having saved/closed/reopened the file?

May be the RTF specification states explicitly that the field can't store more 520 bytes (not 512)... but I don't find anything about it.

Thanks in advance for any help.

And by the way, do you know some backup field to embed data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by using both \keywords and \description tags.